# Unable to start several processes on desktop created by CreateDesktop API call

Tags: c++, winapi, desktop

I am creating new desktop from my C++ app and then switch to this desktop (by calling `SetThreadDesktop`) to create explorer process there. Then switch back to original desktop. The first problem is that I can't see this desktop in TaskView. And the second (and most important)  problem is that I can't launch several applications (Google Chrome for example) or even open Start menu by pressing start button, but can start notepad for example. However if I create new desktop from task view then everything works fine. So the question is how to create new desktop from C++ application that will allow to create all processes and open start menu?
Here is my code:

```
HDESK CreateDevTestDesktopW(const wchar_t* desktop_name)
{
    wchar_t explorer_path[MAX_PATH];
    HDESK original_desktop;
    HDESK devtest_desktop = NULL;
    STARTUPINFOW startup_info = { 0 };
    PROCESS_INFORMATION process_info = { 0 };
    ExpandEnvironmentStringsW(L"%windir%\\explorer.exe", explorer_path, MAX_PATH - 1);
    devtest_desktop = CreateDesktopW(desktop_name, NULL, NULL, 0, GENERIC_ALL, NULL);
    original_desktop = GetThreadDesktop(GetCurrentThreadId());
    if (SetThreadDesktop(devtest_desktop))
    {
        startup_info.cb = sizeof(startup_info);
        startup_info.lpDesktop = LPWSTR(desktop_name);

        CreateProcessW(explorer_path, NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &startup_info, 
&process_info);
        SetThreadDesktop(original_desktop);
    }

    return devtest_desktop;
}
```

Comment: Task View manages **virtual** desktops, not real desktops.

Comment: @RaymondChen then what the difference between real and virtual desktops? What kind of desktop does `CreateDesktop` create?

Answer (score 1):

As @RaymondChen said, [TaskView which manages **virtual** desktops uses IVirtualDesktop, IVirtualDesktopManager, IVirtualDesktopNotification, etc](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/f583b07e-833f-4113-9be1-b084c73e7d8f/windows-10-virtual-desktops-vs-win32api-createdesktop).
In order to [Start an Interactive Client Process in C++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//aa379608(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN), *it's necessary to add access control entries (ACEs) to the discretionary access control list (DACL) of the **interactive** window station and desktop*. Then calling the ImpersonateLoggedOnUser function to ensure that it has access to the client's executable file and the CreateProcessAsUser function creates the client's process.
[There is a related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15158888/createprocessasuser-from-service-and-user-security-issues).